# If Network connection failed, checking until conected or until press Cancel button

Tags: vb.net

I'm checking network availability from `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable`. If connection fails error message trigger.

I want to know, if user click RETRY Button, how this checking continue. With in few minutes I want to fire this message again after connection failed. Again continue the same process until connected or until user press CANCEL button.

My sample code available below.

```
If Not NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable Then ' Network Connectivity Not-Available            
    Dim msgResultC As MsgBoxResult = MessageBox.Show("No Network Connectivity.", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
    If msgResultC = MsgBoxResult.Retry Then
```

Comment: Use a loop that  contains your code. If retry then stay in the loop and run that code again and at cancel the loop finishes.

Comment: You might find the [NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.networkavailabilitychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) useful.